# InfiniteAjaxScroll TypeError: $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, silverstripe, jquery-ias

Hi I am trying to use Infinite Ajax Scroll in Silverstripe.

The setup is as described in the Getting Started Page 
http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/getting-started.html and the "jquery-ias.min.js" is referenced with an include statement on my Page.ss Template AFTER including jquery.js

But regardless how I am trying, I get: `TypeError: $ is undefined`

Any idea what I am missing out? THX!

Page.ss

```
<% require javascript('framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js') %>
<% require javascript('framework/thirdparty/jquery-tools/jquery.tools.min.js') %>
<% require javascript('framework/thirdparty/jquery-ias.min.js') %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$ThemeDir}/javascript/script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// jQuery.noConflict(); <-- uncommenting jQuery.noConflict solves it!

(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var ias = jQuery.ias({
          container:  '#posts',
          item:       '.post',
          pagination: '#pagination',
          next:       '.next'
        });
     });
}(jQuery));
```

Markup

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post">...</div>
    <div class="post">...</div>
</div>

<div id="pagination">
    <a href="/page2/" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually need the noconflict? That error simply means `no jQuery loaded`

Comment: @Martijn you're right! noconflict solves the problem! THX

Comment: On what line of code do you get the TypeError?

Comment: taking out jQuery.noConflict() is the solution

Comment: glad you solved it, could you please post an answer and accept it to mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to leave `jQuery.noConflict();` away!

```
// jQuery.noConflict(); <-- uncommenting jQuery.noConflict solves it!

(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var ias = jQuery.ias({
          container:  '#posts',
          item:       '.post',
          pagination: '#pagination',
          next:       '.next'
        });
     });
}(jQuery));
```